# Groovy wait/notify

Tags: groovy, wait, synchronized, notify

I have the following Groovy code:

```
abstract class Actor extends Script {
    synchronized void proceed() {
        this.notify()
    }

    synchronized void pause() {
        wait()
    }
}

class MyActor extends Actor {
    def run() {
        println "hi"
        pause()
        println "hi again"
    }
}

def theactor = new MyActor()
theactor.run()
theactor.proceed()
```

When I run the code, I want the code to output "hi" and "hi again". Instead, it just stops at "hi" and gets stuck on the pause() function. Any idea on how I could continue the program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Brian says, multithreading and concurrency is a huge area, and it is easier to get it wrong, than it is to get it right...

To get your code working, you'd need to have something like this:

```
abstract class Actor implements Runnable {
  synchronized void proceed() { notify() }
  synchronized void pause()   { wait()   }
}

class MyActor extends Actor {
  void run() {
    println "hi"
    pause()
    println "hi again"
  }
}


def theactor = new MyActor()             // Create an instance of MyActor
def actorThread = new Thread( theactor ) // Create a Thread to run this instance in
actorThread.start()                      // Thread.start() will call MyActor.run()
Thread.sleep( 500 )                      // Make the main thread go to sleep for some time so we know the actor class is waiting
theactor.proceed()                       // Then call proceed on the actor
actorThread.join()                       // Wait for the thread containing theactor to terminate
```

However, if you are using Groovy, I would seriously consider using [a framework like Gpars](http://gpars.codehaus.org/) which brings concurrency to Groovy and is written by people who really know their stuff.  I can't think of anything that llows this sort of arbitrary pausing of code however...  Maybe you could design your code to fit one of their usage patterns instead?

Comment: What I'm doing is making scripted NPCs for a game. I will trigger the proceed function when the player interacts with the NPC. Thanks for the link to Gpars; I'll look into it.

Comment: I'd have a look at this chapter [here on Actors](http://www.gpars.org/guide/guide/5.%20Actors.html). Not sure how well actors scale to the potentially tousands+ you might need for a game?  Might be worth asking on [the mailing list](http://xircles.codehaus.org/lists/user@gpars.codehaus.org)?

Comment: Thanks for the links. I tried out your code and it didn't work correctly, though. I just resorted to checking a boolean every server tick. I looked at Gpars and decided I didn't really need it. Thanks for the help, though.

Answer (score 2):

Threading is a big topic and there are libraries in Java to do many common things without working with the Thread API directly.  One simple example for 'Fire and Forget' is [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html).

But to answer your immediate question; another thread needs to notify your thread to continue.  See the [docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28%29) on wait()

> Causes current thread to wait until another thread invokes the
>   notify() method or the notifyAll() method for this object. In other
>   words, this method behaves exactly as if it simply performs the call
>   wait(0).

One simple 'fix' is to just add a fixed duration to your wait call just to continue with your exploration.  I would suggest the book '[Java Concurrency in Practice](http://jcip.net/)'.

```
synchronized void pause() {
        //wait 5 seconds before resuming.
        wait(5000)
    }
```